# Problem related to First Order Logic. Not able to approach the problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, computational-mathematics

**Problem Statement:**
Consider the first order logic sentence:
$$\mathbf \phi \equiv \exists s\exists t\exists u \forall v \forall w \forall x \forall y\; \psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$$
where $\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$ is a quantifier-free first order logic formula using only predicate symbols, and possibly equality, but no function symbols.
Suppose $\phi$ has a model with a universe containing 7 elements.
Which of the following statements is necessarily true?

(A) There exists at least one model of $\phi$ with a universe of size $\leq3$.
(B) There exists no model of $\phi$ with a universe size $\leq3$.
(C) There exists no model of $\phi$ with a universe size $\gt7$.
(D) Every model of $\phi$ has a universe of size $=7$.

I wanted to know the approach to solve this problem, as from the I do understand that:
A FOL is defined using $\phi$ which contains only predicate symbols and equality and $\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$ is defined over a domain of discourse containing only 7 elements, but I am not able to understand how to deduce anything from the given information.

The explanation given for the solution is:
[image: Solution for the given problem]

**P.S** There is one doubt which I have when checking whether the given propositional/predicate logic is valid or not. As per the definition of the validity of a logic:
"A propositional formula is called valid when it evaluates to **T** no matter what truth values are assigned to the individual propositional variables."
Does that mean that if a formula is valid then it's a tautology?
E.g: $S = p \implies q \; and \;T = \lnot q \implies \lnot p$ then $S \iff T$ is always true, means tautology.

Comment: Yes : a propositional formula that is valid (i.e. true in very interpretation) is called a *tautology*. But in case of FOL there are valid formulas, like e.g. $\forall x (x=x)$ that are **not** tautologies of prop logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! but the claim which you made about FOL, that $\forall x(x=x)$ are not tautologies of propositional logic, but if I define a domain $Z^+$ then $\forall x \in Z^+$ the propositional function $p(x) : \text{"x = x"}$ will be true, hence it will be tautology and valid, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: I mean that the above is a valid FOL formula that is not a tautology in prop logic. See your def : what are the "individual propositional variables" ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In FOL if a formula is a tautology doesn't mean that it is valid. For. e.g $\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \implies \forall x \forall y P(y,x)$ is valid but not a tautology in FOL.

Comment: The edited-in book solution seems to be completely nonsensical and not in line with how first-order logic usually works.

Comment: @SurajSharma: All tautologies are valid, but not all valid formulas are tautologies.

Answer (score 2):

The key fact is that since $\psi$ has no quantifiers, its meaning does not depend on the domain.

Now, notice that the statement asserts the existence of three elements of the domain (which may be equal to one another) that satisfy the universal formula. What if you restrict your seven element model to only consist of these three (or possibly one or two) objects?

**Edit**
More details.

As Ross Millikan has noted, answers B,C,D can be ruled out by taking $\psi$ to be something always true, e.g. $s=s.$ In this case, any (non-empty) structure is a model of $\phi,$ in particular, there is a model of every size, which conflicts with B-D. The "solution" you screenshotted says that the three existential quantifiers means there are at least three elements, but this is wrong since $s,t,$ and $u$ could all be the same element. (And this is the only statement in the solution that even makes sense to me... the rest seems like complete nonsense.)

A is correct. Let $M_7$ be the seven-element model that exists by assumption. Then there are an $s,t,u\in M_7$ such that for all $v,w,x,y\in M_7,$ $\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$ holds in $M_7$. Choose any such $s,t,u$ and let $M_3$ have domain $\{s,t,u\}.$ As explained before, it is possible that $s,t$ and $u$ are not distinct, so $M_3$ has between $1$ and $3$ elements.

$M_3$ can be considered as a substructure of $M_7$ with respect to the language consisting of all the symbols that occur in $\phi.$ There are no function symbols (and I presume this means no constant symbols since they also say "only" predicate symbols), so there is no issue with $M_3$ being closed under the functions. So all you have to do to get symbol interpretations for $M_3$ is just restrict the interpretation of the relation symbols for $M_7$ to the subset $\{s,t,u\}.$

Now we can argue that $\phi$ is satisfied in $M_3$ and thus $M_3$ is a model of $\phi$ of size $\le 3.$ This means we need to show there are an $s,t,u\in M_3$ such that for all $v,w,x,y\in M_3,$ $\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$ holds in $M_3.$ We simply take $s,$ $t$ and $u$ to be the very same elements we chose from the domain of $M_7$ to comprise the domain of $M_3.$

We must show that $\forall v,w,x,y(\psi(s,t,u,w,x,y))$ still holds true in $M_3$. Well, we know that it is true in $M_7,$ i.e. for any $v,w,x,y\in M_7,$ $\psi(s,t,u,w,x,y)$ holds in $M_7.$ Since the domain of $M_3$ is a subset of $M_3,$ this implies that for all $v,w,x,y \in M_3,$ $\psi(s,t,u,w,x,y)$ holds in $M_7.$

So we just need to show that the fact that $\psi(s,t,u,w,x,y)$ holds in $M_7$ means it holds in $M_3$ as well. This follows from the fact that $\psi$ has no quantifiers. Thus it is a propositional function of atomic sentences of the form $x=y$ or $R(x,y,\ldots)$ for predicate symbols $R.$ But, since all the predicate symbols' interpretations are just the restrictions of their interpretations in $M_7,$ the atomic sentences hold in $M_3$ if and only if they hold in $M_7.$ Thus any propositional function of these atomic sentences holds in $M_3$ if and only if it holds in $M_7.$ And we're done.

Comment: Thanks! if I am correct in the problem, $\psi$ is FOL which is defined over a domain/universe which contains only 7 elements and out of these the statement asserts only the existence of 3 elements which is s,t, and u. Now as the statement value doesn't depend on the domain as its quantifier-free, does that mean that $\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)$ doesn't contain any of the variables $(s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)$ in it. Can you tell me what it means if one says "$p(x)$ is a quantifier-free first-order logic formula using only predicate symbols, and possibly equality, but no function symbols."

Comment: No, it depends on the variables. It’s just that for a given assignment of variables, the truth value of the sentence does not change if we change the domain (while still including whatever elements the variables are assigned to). I’m not sure what part of the sentence you ask about is unclear, but perhaps it will be less doubtful with the above issue cleared up.

Comment: Actually I am having difficulty understanding this part of the question "$\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y)$ is a quantifier free FOL using only predicate symbols, and possibly equality, but no function symbols", although the answer is **(B)** and you are correct and I do understood that the $\phi$ value doesn't depend upon the domain as there is no quantifier's, just a set of predicates which is either true or false. But how you deduce that the statement asserts the existence of 3 elements of the domain which satisfy the universal formula. Can you please explain me, using some examples?

Comment: Why can't $\psi$ be simply True?  Then $ \phi$ is True in any model that has at least one element.

Comment: @RossMillikan It can... have I said it can't?

Comment: It seemed like you were agreeing with choice B, which prohibits models of less than three elements, though it wasn't explicit.  As I think on it, I would pick D but without conviction on the basis that you could add a new element to the seven element model and make it act just like one that is already there.

Comment: @RossMillikan No, I'm saying it is (A). Am I confused? (I was definitely confused when I said your remark led to a simplified solution, so I deleted that comment).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96289/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Comment: @SurajSharma I wrote a full solution.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can find a $\psi$ to disprove $B,C,D$ now that $C$ has been edited.  For $B, C,D$ you can just use $\psi=True$ and note that you can have a model with six or eight elements.

Comment: @RossMilikan The answer is (B).

Comment: @SurajSharma:  spaceisdarkgreen agreed with my example in a comment.

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought we had sorted out that the correct answer is (A) and that the counterexample of pairwise distinct s,t,u,v doesn't work since then $\phi$ would be unsatisfiable.

Comment: @SurajSharma Ross is certainly right that there is an easy counterexample that shows (B) cannot be correct. The answer (at least in my opinion) is (A), and that's where my hint/answer is going.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I have updated the problem statement with the solution screenshot, I am still having a confusion, that you are saying (A), the answer is rather (B).

Comment: @SurajSharma That solution is, frankly, nonsense. Having three existential quantifiers doesn't mean there needs to be at least three elements: the same element could be witness for all three. The rest of what it says is completely inscrutable to me.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah that's what I thought, so I posted here to understand how to solve these type of problem encountered, according to you, do you there should be more information available?

Comment: @SurajSharma:  The solution claims because there is a model with seven elements that is the maximum size of a model.  This is silly.  Also, sentences do not belong to models, elements do.  It makes no sense.

Comment: @SurajSharma:  with the edit to C none of the choices are true.  My example of $\psi=True$ rules out the new one as well.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't understand this part of the problem which says "$\psi(s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)$ is is a quantifier-free first-order logic formula using only predicate symbols, and possibly equality, but no function symbols".

Comment: That means it can have things like $x=y$ and $P(z)$ but not $u=w+v$.  I thought functions could be turned into predicates, so we could define $S(u,w,v)$ to be $u=w+v$ but I haven't looked at it for a long time.

Comment: (Related to a now deleted part of the answer). There is not _necessarily_ a model with $8$ elements. For example this is not the case if $\psi$ is $$ \bigl [ (p_1(x)\land p_1(y)\to x=y)\land \cdots \land(p_7(x)\land p_7(y)\to x=y)\bigr] \land (p_1(x)\lor p_2(x)\lor\cdots\lor p_7(x)) $$